# Docker compose for nginx, streamlit, and mariadb

Tags: docker, dockerfile, mariadb, streamlit

I am not exactly sure how to go about this. I have an instance in AWS Lightsail that has a static IP for which the IP department granted access to read from MariaDB database. I am using streamlit for my app and have stored my database credentials in a .env file. After, I have copied the file code and dockerized it (running the following command):

```
docker-compose up --build -d
```

It is built successfully, but when I use the static IP to look at the web page I get the following error:

**OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address)")**

Is there something I have to do either in docker or with MariaDB? Thank you in advance.

File of docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
    app:
        container_name: app
        restart: always
        build: ./app
        ports:
            - "8501:8501"
        command: streamlit run Main.py

    database:
        image: mariadb:latest
        volumes:
        - /data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        restart: always
        env_file: .env

    nginx:
        container_name: nginx
        restart: always
        build: ./nginx
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        depends_on:
            - app
            - database
```

I am not sure how the streamlit app is connected with mariadb here.

Comment: Please post your docker-compose file as well.

Comment: @m19v Thanks, I just edited to add the docker-compose file.

Comment: You are trying to connect to the mariadb with the hostname localhost, thats unfortunatly cant be true, as you run it in another docker container. i don't see where streamlit tries to connect to your database, but you gotta change that to the name of the running docker container.

You can get the container names with "docker ps"

Comment: You need to use the service name defined in your `docker-compose.yaml` (`mysql`) as the hostname for your database connection, rather than `localhost`.

Comment: @larsks I did update it to the service name but I get the same error after running the command docker compose build. Also, I have an IP address for mariadb host connection. If I replace host by the service name, then where do I actually have to put the host IP address that connects to MariaDB. Thanks